# MySQL Return Today's Records Using DATE from DATETIME Field

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime, where-clause

I have a table called "actions" with a `DATETIME` column called "occurred". I'm trying to return the records for today by doing the following

```
SELECT * FROM `actions` WHERE `occurred` = DATE(NOW());
```

But I get an empty result set. If I take the `WHERE` clause out, I can see all 295 rows in the table and there's at least 30 rows from today. Later I will be writing another query to return all records between today's date and X amount of days in the past but before I can get there I need to know why this query is returning an empty result set.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there in no future date in `occurred`, you could just use below:

```
SELECT * FROM `actions` WHERE `occurred` > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: This works great. There will be no future data. It will be strictly for comparing NOW against historical entries. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT * FROM actions WHERE DATE(ocurred) = CURDATE();
```

`DATE(ocurred)` ignores the time part.

Here's the SQL Fiddle to play with the data: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81708/2